# De-/Serialize binary data

Tags: java, serialization, binary, jackson, ormlite

I am currently reverse engeneering the binary network protocol of an mmorpg.
I am implementing the protocol in java.

For each packet-type,
I will create a class that represents the binary data.

For example, Chat-Packet ("asd")

```
header = 0c75
03 00 61 73 64 00   . . a s d .
```

java code:

```
public class Chat {
  private short length;
  private String msg;
}
```

Is there a library to deserialize the byte array directly into the object. Basically something like Jackson or OrmLite for binary data.

Anyone know if there is a library that can be used?
I already searched here and on google, but didn't find what I was looking for.
I even started writing my own Serializer.

Comment: [Protocol buffers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/) might help you?

Comment: Yeah i already had a look at protocol buffer, but I could not find any information about how they serialize the data. It is crucial that I can control the order in which the fields are populated, as I do not have any control on the data that i receive from the server. I also do not really like the idea to define my data structure and then have to compile it into java.

Comment: the server would need to implement it on their end, and on yours so that its singing from the same hymn sheet, so that's out the window.will the data coming from server be binary? Either way, you'd need to implement a byte array of some kind, with a gotcha, how would you know the begin/end of packet data?

Comment: yes the data from the server is binary. each packet is prefixed with its length, so that is not a problem. But I can not change the protocol of the server, as the protocol already exists and I am only reverse engineering it

Comment: If it is binary data, you probably don't want to store it in a `String`.
Pass the binary data to the constructor of your class and parse the data there.

Answer (score 0):

every Serialization library (that I know of?) defines its own binary format - so the binary representation is completely determined by the class / idl file and cannot be tailored to match a custom protocol. common binary formats:

- [protobuf](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/encoding)
- [avro](https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.8.1/spec.html#binary_encoding)
- [BSON](http://bsonspec.org/spec.html)

if the protocol youre reverse-engineering doesnt happen to be a common one (maybe theyre using proto internally?) then your only option is to implement [Serializable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html)/[Externalizable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Externalizable.html) yourself, or maybe bring in [kryo](https://github.com/EsotericSoftware/kryo) and define your own custom (de)serializers - either way you will be writing the Object <--> byte[]/stream/buffer conversion logic yourself.